# Chrome Custom Tabs navigate from Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-pendingintent, chrome-custom-tabs

I'm implemented Chrome Custom Tabs in my project and added two ToolbarItems. With these items I want to give the user the possibility to navigate forward and backwards within the Chrome Custom Tabs.

But when on the first page and pressing back it will close and not show the forward button. When forward is possible show the button and make it work.

After more then 20 hours of research and trying I still can't talk to the Chrome Custom Tabs. I can't even call onBackPressed() because I don't own the activity. When getting the topActivity it's package name is com.android.chrome.

Does anyone know how I can communicate with the Custom Tab thingie.

Below the code of my CustomTabsIntent and the Pending intent.

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    builder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SharedInstance.getContext(), R.color.vindenOrangeLight));
    builder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(SharedInstance.getContext(), R.color.vindenOrangeLight));
    builder.setShowTitle(true);

    builder.addToolbarItem(1, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(SharedInstance.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_back), "Terug", backIntent());
    builder.addToolbarItem(2, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(SharedInstance.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_arrow_forward), "Voorwaarts", forwardIntent());

    CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

    customTabsIntent.launchUrl(SharedInstance.getContext(), Uri.parse(url));
```